# Using a variable inside a variable objective-C

Tags: objective-c, xcode, variables, uiimageview, int

EDIT: {
No longer need help!

I used tags and a bunch of loops to reference them at anytime.
I never knew you could store so many images in one UIImageView!
}

I have an application that deals with a a lot of images and what i want to do is use an integer inside the variable name so i don't have to write code for each image. Ex:

```
 - (void)addIconClicked {
 if (icons < 28) {
      icons += 1;
 }

 if (icons == 2) {
 UIImageView * iconImage2 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"icon1.png"]];
 //modify image view like setting the frame, setting the title, etc... (not important)
 }

 else if (icons == 3) {
 // iconImage 3 set up
 }
```

this continues all the way up to iconImage26!

so i was wondering if i could use the integer "icons" as part of the variable name so i don't have to run the code 26 different times!!

Ex:

```
 - (void)addIconClicked {
  if (icons < 28) {
  icons += 1;
  }

 /*some how insert the "icons" int where (icons) is. Like NSString uses 
 stringWithFormat ([NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", icons])*/
 UIImageView * iconImage(icons) = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"icon%i.png", icons]]];
 }
```

-----edit----- (to clarify what i want)

my problem is that i want to make an unlimited amount of image views but if i use the same variable more than once, it would show up on the view fine, but it would be released and i can't edit it anymore.
 Ex:

```
 - (void)addIconClicked {
 if (icons < 28) {
  icons += 1;
  }

 NSString * iconName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"icon%i.png", icons];
 //if i ran this 100 times, 100 images would show up, but i can no longer edit any of them except the newest.
 iconImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:iconName]];
 }
```

so i need to know how to make an unlimited amount of images that i can still edit individually.

i thought i might be able to use the integer's value inside a variable name when i create it, but i guess i can't:(

so if anyone knows, please explain!!

so to sum it up...

my exact problem is that i want to create an unlimited number of UIImageView's using a different image each time.
You think i could just use 1 variable for all of the images (which would show up) but then i can't edit them at all because they are released.

I just need a way to create an unlimited amount of Global UIImageViews that i can edit and access at any time.

Comment: The short answer is yes. Have you actually tried it? If, so, is there a specific problem?

Comment: i just need to know how to use a variables value, inside a variable name.

Comment: so if the int "icons" is 2 i can put it in the name without using the first example with the if statement

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is with an array.

```
NSMutableArray* allIcons = [NSMutableArray array]; //First, you'll need this empty array.

//Then, when you create your icon...
NSString* iconName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"icon%lx.png",icons];
UIImageView * newIcon = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:iconName]];
[allIcons addObject:newIcon]; //This adds the icon at the next index, starting at 0.
```

Then, when you use your icons, instead of `icon1`, `icon2`, and so on, use `[allIcons objectAtIndex:0]`, `[allIcons objectAtIndex:1]`, and so on.

This is a pretty common concept--you should consider checking out a few beginning Cocoa tutorials; you might find it in use.

Comment: Not seeing any advantage with an array in what he is wanting to do: generate a string on the fly based on a base name + int.

Comment: Will i be able to use the image globally if the array is global but the imageview isn't?

Comment: Any place you could use 26 individual variables, you could be using an array instead. Either go through some tutorials or show us your *exact* problem.

Comment: my exact problem is that i want to create an unlimited number of UIImageView's using a different image each time. You think i could just use 1 variable for all of the images (which would show up) but then i can't edit them at all because they are released. I just need a way to create an unlimited amount of Global UIImageViews that i can edit and access at any time.

Comment: My solution does exactly that--you add the views to an array, then access them by number (called an index). Did you try it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use an array for storing UIImageView references. Or you can set their tags and find them later using viewWithTag.

EDIT: Ok I am home now and I can explain:

Use tagging:

```
UIImageView * anImageView= [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat@"icon%i.png",icons]]];
anImageView.tag=icons;
[parentView addSubview: anImageView];


UIImageView *theOneYouWant = (UIImageView)[parentView viewWithTag:someTag];
```

or use a c-array of UIImageView pointers to store references if you don't mind scope:

```
UIImageView * imageViews[28]; // put this into class interface
imageViews[icons]= [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat@"icon%i.png",icons]]];
```

Comment: so i can put the integers value inside the variable name??

Comment: Actually no, practically yes. You can not create variable names in this fashion generally, but you can achieve what you want using arrays. You need to see some tutorial and get a full comprehension about variables and arrays concept, I believe.

Comment: I fully get how i could access each icon without doing the code for each one in another method, but when i create the icons i don't, i need a method to create an unlimited amount of icons 1 at a time (whenever the add button is clicked) that i can edit and access at any time.

Comment: Like in your comment, the anImageView is only one variable so when i run the method again, the image will be released and another one will show up.  so if i run your first example 100 times, i will have 100 images, but i can only edit the 100th

Comment: Images don't get released, you just lose your reference to them, which you can get anytime you want using viewWithTag.

Comment: but how do i reference them through touchesBegan? I want detect if someone touches inside the Icon but if i don't already have reference to them, how do i know if they're touched?

Comment: This is another question. You can try using UIButton with custom type (you can put images on them easily), or you can use touchesBegan event after overriding canBecomeFirstResponder and setting userInteractionEnabled. As I've said this is another question.